# Reg Google Earth Engine code editor suggestion tooltip

Tags: google-earth-engine, javascript

When I try to create or copy geometries in GEE editor, I am not getting suggestion tooltip to convert geometries into import records. Its working for my other Gmail account. Having issue with other account[image]. I have attached the screenshot. As you can see, Its not showing suggestion tooltip. I tried to change the browser, cleared cache, history but still no use.

Answer (score 1):

There's a setting under the gear icon: `underline code suggestions`.
Turn it on then reload the code editor.

Comment: I did that still its not working. Its giving suggestion tool tip for other things. its not working for only my account